# Missing wxversion when using matplotlib with wxPython/Phoenix in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, wxpython

I want to use `matplotlib` with `wxPython` (more concret: `wxPhoenix`) in `Python3`. But the code below doesn't work because of missing `wxversion`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
```

There is no Ubuntu-package `python3-wxversion`, no `pip3`-package.
btw: With Python2 I can import `wxversion`.
I used the `matplotlib` from Ubuntu-Repository (`1.3.1`) and the upgraded one with pip3.

How can I install `wxversion` for Python3 and why is that missing?

I am using `wxPython-Phoenix (3.0.3.dev1820+49a8884)`.

Comment: mpl does not support wx phoenix + python3 except on the master branch right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many other issues with mpl and wxPython Phoenix, there is a PR https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3421 which was merged in May, but I am not sure if there has been a release of mpl since then.  I think it is in 1.5dev1, but not sure, please check with the mpl devs.